# Remove a row on uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  a table(1) with checkbox against each row. When i click a checkbox its value is shown in another table(2). In table(2) each row has a remove option. If i click remove, the row will be removed. In the same way if i uncheck the checkbox in table(1), the corresponding row in table(2) should be removed.So how should i remove a row on uncheck.I have placed this part of code in else block.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.isSelected').click(function() {

     var pdtname = $(this).attr('data-productname');

     if ( $('.isSelected:checked').length > 0) {
        $("#result").show();

        var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('tfoo');
        var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('rfoo').text(pdtname);
        var link = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);">/a>').addClass('lfoo').text('Remove');

           row.append(link);
           table.append(row);
           $('#result').append(table);

           $("#result").on('click','.lfoo',function(){
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }); 

    } else {
           $('.isSelected[data-productname="pdtname"]').on('click','.lfoo',function(){
                        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                    }); 
                }
            }); 
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="result" ></div> 

<td><form method='post' action='<c:url value="compareproducts.html"/>' >
            <input class="isSelected" type="checkbox" name='id' value='${product.id}'
                    data-productname="${product.productName}" >
    </form>
```

Comment: It's a bit tough without seeing the HTML code with the IDs and classes. My best guess is that the code in the `else` part is adding a handler to the `click` event on something (a checkbox?) and does not really remove anything by itself... but that's a guess.

Comment: As I mentioned on the previous comment, modifying the `else` part to take the removal action instead of adding a handler for the `click` event seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/4g8nL9t5/

Comment: But its not working on project. I mean if i add only one product it works. But not when i have more.

Comment: Take into account that I only worked with a small/generic snippet of code. You will need to change more than what I showed in the jsfiddle to make it work on your project. For example: you may want to add an ID to the created row, this ID will link it unequivocally to the checkbox so you can remove it when it is unchecked.

Comment: Just started learning all these stuff. I cannot use data-productname to remove?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64131/discussion-between-alvaro-montoro-and-user3844782).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our conversation in the chat. A quick solution would be to add a `data-productname` to the table so when you uncheck a checkbox, it removes the table with the same `data-productname` (notice that for this to work, the productname must be unique).

You can see an example on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4g8nL9t5/1/

Comment: A quick update so the table is fully removed (instead of only the tbody), and so the checkbox is automatically unchecked when the remove link is clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/4g8nL9t5/3/

Comment: I'm not too clear what you are trying to achieve, but I replied on the chat with what is possibly the answer.